# How put different component to dataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

The last I wanted to do `dataGrid` with columns with `comboBox`, `checkBox`, `button` and some others. I'm interesting why I can't do sth like that:

- define `dataGrid` with `comboBoxColumn` (similarly other)
- create `comboBox`: `ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();`
- add this `combo` to `dataGrid`

I know that is the way to add `comboBox, checkBox, button, image to grid`. But why can't do it so easy? For example when I want create dataGrid with comboBox with event on selection change it isn't easy to do it. Or maybe I don't know how do it.

So, I have question, what do you think about it and how you manage with this problem? Do you think someday it will be so easy? Maybe you have some class or tutorial which can resolve this problem?

## edit

Problem in Win Forms

Answer (score 0):

This will never be easy. Adding a column dynamically is very difficult because every row in the dataGrid needs to be updated. And I can't think of a scenario where suddenly adding comboboxes to every row would be usefull, also you would need to have tons of information at the ready to fill the combo boxes.